# How do I add an environment variable to wsl.exe?

Tags: environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

A program that I have no control over (it's actually PyCharm) launches

```
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 -- wget <link>
```

The download fails because my system runs behind a proxy. Within WSL, I have set the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`. They would get picked up if the program ran the command

```
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 -- /bin/bash -lc "wget <link>"
```

because this launches bash in login shell mode which reads in `bashrc` etc.. However, that does not happen and I need to make it work with only `wsl.exe`.

How can I set environment variables that are picked up when launching `wsl.exe` (without `bash -lc`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I did not find out how to add environment variables that are used on launch of `wsl.exe`, I found out how to instruct **wget** to use a proxy by default.

Add to `/etc/wgetrc` the following lines:

```
use_proxy=yes
http_proxy=<proxy:port>
https_proxy=<proxy:port>
```

Also **curl** can be instructed to use a proxy by default, just add the following line to `/etc/curlrc`:

```
proxy=<proxy:port>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the environment variables in a config file that is loaded for your shell in non-login,non-interactive mode.

To verify that the method works you can run `wsl -- env` from windows cmd.

**For zsh:**
Put it inside `~/.zshenv`

```
export http_proxy=<proxy:port>
export https_proxy=<proxy:port>
```

**For Bash:**

I believe you'd have to setup an environment variable `BASH_ENV` in `/etc/environment`. Read more here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394121/which-file-is-loaded-and-executed-by-a-non-interactive-non-login-shell

Comment: Since I cannot modify the call (I don't have control over it, see original post), using zsh is not an option, it has to be bash. I tried defining env vars in `/etc/environment` but unfortunately, they do not get picked up in an non-interactive shell. If you mean to do something else with `BASH_ENV` please be more specific, I'm not sure what to do with it.